# Multithreading in avconv to split video in frames

Tags: ffmpeg, split, frame

I would like to split a video in frames using avconv (ffmpeg fork). To speed up the process I want to use multithreading. For this I use "-threads 3" on a VM with 4 cores. I see no difference between "-threads 1" and "-threads 3" in top (always between 100%-130%.

The command:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 frames/frame-%05d.tiff -threads 3
```

What can I do to speedup the process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The first and probably the biggest slowdown is the fact that you are running on a Virtual Machine. I will assume that it is impossible for you to run the command locally for some reason.

It is possible that the bottleneck is actually your drive. You are reading and writing on the same physical device, and you can try to optimise that. If you have two harddrives you can try to write on a different one. This way there will be significantly less seeking going on on any single one. Please note that different partition on the same physical device will *not* solve this problem, but can pottentially only aggrevate the situation.

Think of the filesystem you are using, make sure that it is optimised for creation of large number of files. Journaling system may actually slow things down somewhat, because you are performin many actions on the FS itself rather than simply adding to the file. Keep in mind that you probably do not want to move your entire system off of the journaling file system, just to gain a little speed of the single action (assuming that this is not the exclusive thing that this machine is doing).